# Problem with Dropdownlist returning default value?

Tags: vb.net

I am new in ASPNET. I am having a problem returning a default value for a dropdownlist. When a user select another value for example

(Names- Value)Private - 1; Friends - 2; Public - 3; (not binded to database but hard coded)

When a user select a value and saved it to a database. How can I return 
a new dafault value for a dropdown?

I tried

dropdownlist1.selectedvalue = 2 (code behind)

and still the dropdownlist view Private instead of Friends.

What will be the solution to this scenario? Please help

Kind Regards 
Jake

Comment: Where (what event) are you setting the selected value?

Comment: I Put this inside the page_load...

Comment: Here's the actual script 
   

'for Company Name 
'Where curValPrivacyFlagTypes is a class that returns an Integer value....
  dpdAccountPrivacy.SelectedValue = curValPrivacyFlagTypes(oDpdvalues).Rows(0)("VisibilityLevelID") 

and this is inside the Page_load. 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely from my memory, but I believe that ".SelectedValue" actually requires the value, not the index. So you could try `dropdownlist1.selectedvalue="Friends - 2"`. Or you could try `dropdownlist1.items.findbyvalue("Friends - 2")` in combination with `dropdownlist1.selectindex()`. Hope some part of that helps!

Comment: Hi Charles!
Inside the Page_load

I tried to  put your suggestion something like this

dpdAccountPrivacy.items.findvalue(curValPrivacyFlagTypes(oDpdvalues).Rows(0)("VisibilityLevelID") )
dpdAccountPrivacy.selectindex() ' 

it doesn't work....

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't more specific Jake. I looked up the relevant pages on MSDN and here is what I think the solution is:

`dpdAccountPrivacy.SelectedIndex = dpdAccountPrivacy.Items.FindValue(curValPrivacyFlagTypes(oDpdvalues).Rows(0)("VisibilityLevelID"))`

You could also do it this way:

`dpdAccountPrivacy.SelectedValue = curValPrivacyFlagTypes(oDpdvalues).Rows(0)("VisibilityLevelID")`

Comment: I just read through the whole thread again, and realized that you indicated your `curValPrivacyFlagTypes(oDpdvalues).Rows(0)("VisibilityLevelID")` item returned an Integer. Herein lies your problem. The Dropdownlist can either assign a selected item based on value/text or index. Value in this case is the value of an object, so the value of a string "Friends" for instance would be the string "Friends" and the index would be 2. You need to do this: `dpdAccountPrivacy.SelectedIndex = curValPrivacyFlagTypes(oDpdvalues).Rows(0)("VisibilityLevelID")`

Comment: Glad I could help! Would you mind checking the accepted answer check? I need all the reputation I can get :-)